# What web server identifies itself as barista/3.3.6?

Tags: web-server

I am trying to identify what web server barista/3.3.6 is.

Below is the response headers for a request that contains barista/3.3.6.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 484
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Server: barista/3.3.6
Set-Cookie: espn360affiliate1=comcast; expires=Mon, 03-Jun-2013 20:08:44 GMT; path=/; domain=go.com;
Set-Cookie: espnAffiliate=comcast; expires=Thu, 06-Dec-2012 12:48:44 GMT; path=/; domain=.go.com;
```

Comment: That'd definitely be Barista 3.3.6...  https://github.com/steadicat/barista

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barista is a web server developed internally at go.com, which is now part of The Walt Disney Company (that also includes ESPN).  It was developed as an alternative to Tomcat (during Tomcat's early days)

Answer (score 4):

[A Barista server might](http://www.basis.com/barista-overview).  Running v 3.3.6, if I had to guess.

(I'd never heard of it before either... and not too surprisingly, Google kept wanting to show me all about serving coffee, and how/where to find jobs serving coffee.)

Answer (score 2):

Or maybe it is something like https://github.com/steadicat/barista
This module has its own server.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure which one it is.. can't find any versioning info on the github link.  Maybe we could ask the site operator.  "By the way, which obscure software suite are you using, barista, or barista?"